# Need AMAZON SQS lib or api to use with C++ project in Visual studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have used **Amazon SQS** DLL file  to understand the working of SQS queue in my C# project

But Now I want to use  **AMAZON SQS in my visual C++ project**  but can't find any related lib file or dll file.